# data transfer from ec2 to s3 bucket with time constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I wanted to know if there is a possibility of transferring data from ec2 to s3 which is older than one month. Basically, if it's possible to apply time constraint in data transfer process or not

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Comment: @Marcin is it somewhere in the doc? Sorry I am unable to find it.

Comment: No its not. This requires custom solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS CLI does not have this capability in-built.

Therefore, you would either need to identify the files separately, and then call the AWS CLI, or you could write a program (eg in Python) that checks the file dates and then copies the files to Amazon S3 using the boto3 library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly from AWS CLI, but you can use a simple python script as below

```
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import time
import os

def put_object(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file to s3
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True


def upload_files(bucket,path):
    current_time = time.time()
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        creation_time = os.path.getctime(file)
        if (current_time - creation_time) // (24 * 3600) >= 30:
            put_object(file, bucket, object_name=None)
            print('{} moved to s3'.format(file))
            #os.unlink(file) <- if you need you can delete file from s3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bucket = "my-s3-bucket"
    path = "path/to/folder"
    upload_files(bucket,path)
```

create a cron job and run this script in any time window you prefer.